# at windows 7 - how to create wifi access point with "open" authentication?

Tags: powershell

win-7
   i set my laptop to be access point but windows force me to use WPA2 as authentication for the user connected  .
i  want to change the  authentication level to OPEN  instead WPA2 how i can do it ?

i used the following commands :

Open cmd window  as administrator and typed  the following commands :

1. netsh wlan set profileorder name="profile1" interface="Wireless Network Connection 4"
2. netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=v2v_AP key=alvarion keyUsage=persistent
3. netsh wlan start hostednetwork

Comment: More suitable for superuser site in my opinion, not related to powershell at all